# Exception thrown: read access violation.during BST Deletion for many elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

so am having problems with the exception during deletion(Exception thrown: read access violation.
parent was 0x158398.)like that sometimes are different numbers etc and always its about parent object/pointer, my code is working without any errors,exceptions till 100k objects then sometimes works sometimes not, for 1 milion is not even working anymore.If anybody could help out would be great. under post am posting code:

Node Class:

```
template <class T>
class Node {

public:
    T data;
    Node<T>* Left = NULL;
    Node<T>* Right = NULL;
};
```

the code for finding min of right subtree:

```
Node<T>* findMin(Node<T>* node)
    {
        while (node->Left != NULL)
            node = node->Left;
        return node;
    }
```

code for Deletion:

```
void Delete(Node<T>*& node) {

    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    Node<T>* parent = findParentForDelete(this->root, node);
    Node<T>* temp = NULL;


    //leafs
    if (node->Left == NULL && node->Right == NULL) {
        if (node == root) {
            delete root;
            root = NULL;
            return;
        }
        else {
            if (parent->Left == node)   //line with exception
                parent->Left = NULL;
            else
                parent->Right = NULL;
            delete node;
            node = NULL;
            return;
        }
    }
    //1 child left not null
    else if (node->Left != NULL && node->Right == NULL)
    {
        if (node == root) {
            temp = root->Left;

            delete root;
            root = NULL;

            root = temp;
            return;

        }
        else {
            if (parent->Left == node)
                parent->Left = node->Left;
            else
                parent->Right = node->Left;

            delete node;
            node = NULL;
            return;

        }
    }
    //1 child Right not null
    else if (node->Left == NULL && node->Right != NULL)
    {
        if (node == root) {
            temp = root->Right;

            delete root;
            root = NULL;

            root = temp;
            return;
        }
        else {
            if (parent->Left == node)
                parent->Left = node->Right;
            else
                parent->Right = node->Right;

            delete node;
            node = NULL;
            return;
        }
    }
    //2 childs
    else if (node->Left != NULL && node->Right != NULL)
    {
        temp = findMin(node->Right);
        T data = temp->data;
        Delete(temp);
        node->data = data;
}
}
```

finding parent:

```
Node<T>* findParentForDelete(Node<T>* node, Node<T>*& nodeToFind)
    {
        if (node == NULL)
            return NULL;

        if (node->Left == NULL && node->Right == NULL)
            return NULL;

        if ((node->Left != NULL && node->Left == nodeToFind)
            || (node->Right != NULL && node->Right == nodeToFind))
            return node;

        if (node->data->age > nodeToFind->data->age)
            return findParentForDelete(node->Left, nodeToFind);

        if (node->data->age < nodeToFind->data->age)
            return findParentForDelete(node->Right, nodeToFind);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use some kind of memory debugger like e.g. [Valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org/) for POSIX environments?

Comment: *exceptions till 100k objects t* -- Unless this is some sort of infinite recursion or deep recursion issue, the problem more than likely has nothing to do with the number of entries.

Comment: thanks for tip about valgrind! didnt know about that tbf as am not too experienced in c++ programming definitely will try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findParentForDelete` does not always return a value.

It will not return a value if the node you're looking for has an age that is the same as a different node in the tree, so the value returned to the caller will be a garbage value.

If you increase the warning level when you compile, most  compilers will issue a warning for this.

Comment: Also, to find such errors and confirm it is an error, a `std::cout << "Oops..." << std::endl;` could be placed right before the ending `}` of the function that is supposed to return a value.  If that output shows up, then that's confirmation the program is broken.